# Encrypting sqlite database with SQLiteCrypt

Tags: sqlite

I am rally struggling with finding solution to protect sqlite database with password. I am trying with SQLiteCrypt. I followed insttruction from [a link](http://sqlite-crypt.com/documentation.htm)! , but when i type;

```
sqlite3_open_v2("data.db", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);
```

i am getting: Error: near "sqlite3_open_v2": syntax error.
Can someone help?

Comment: Where do you type this? Please include more of your code.

Comment: I think I see your problem -- SQLite is not supported in Fortran.

Comment: I downloaded zip file which contains sqlite.exe, then in cmd i type sqlite.exe data.db and then sqlite3_open_v2("data.db", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);.  Explanation on the site is very bad and i can't find any example on the net.

Comment: The code in your question is C. You can not enter this at the `sqlite` command prompt. The code in [the docs](http://sqlite-crypt.com/documentation.htm) is C code you are supposed to use in a [SQLite C program](https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html).

Comment: Hm, didn't know about that, thank you for link i will definitely read it. But can you give me some tips like do i need compiler for c and where should i enter this code?

Comment: Read the [Little C Primer](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Little_C_Primer).

Comment: If you want to issue commands from the command prompt, see [this page](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html).  Also, type `.help` (note the "dot") inside the sqlite command prompt for some quick help.

Comment: Hot Licks link you recommended doesn't helps much because it is all about regular sqllite queries, i am interested in encrypting database so it implies that I already know using command line, but i am confused how can i use that zip file i downloaded from SQLiteCrypt site, i thought that i need to type in command line code from link i put above. Also i can see that sqlite has C interface and it is not clear to me if i need to compile code away from command line than why do i downloaded zip file from official site.

Answer (score -1):

```
D:\>sqlite.exe data.db
SQLite version 3.7.15.2 2013-01-09 11:53:05
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> PRAGMA lic = '77523-009-0000007-72328';
sqlite> PRAGMA rekey = 'ac23';
sqlite> .exit
```

You MUST exit first to see the effect!

```
D:\>sqlite.exe data.db
SQLite version 3.7.15.2 2013-01-09 11:53:05
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select * from _MapPropertyA;
Error: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

DONE, your database file encrypted

Comment: This doesn't work, i can enter database with my sqliteManager.

Comment: Works here. I'm then using Navicat to connect and then error message appear (26-file is encrypted or is not a database)

Comment: What is the line PRAGMA lic = ... for? Is that some licence key? That's probably why it works for you and noone else :)

Comment: Didn't work for me either, even with PRAGMA lic = '775...'